# Clipping annotations in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to set a clip bounds for `matplotlib.text.Annotation`?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
vals = [
        (10,20,"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"),
        (30,20, "Pellentesque scelerisque congue fermentum."),
        (50,10, "Aliquam erat volutpat")
]
ax.set_ylim(0,1)
ax.broken_barh(map(lambda v: v[:2],vals), (0, 1), facecolors=('yellow','red','green'))
for v in vals:
    ax.annotate(
        v[2], 
        xy=(v[0],0.4), 
        clip_on=True, 
        clip_box=Bbox([[v[0],0],[v[0]+v[1],1]])
    )

plt.show()
```

I've tried to set `clip_box` & `clip_path` on `ax.annotate` calls, but this is not working.
[image]

Comment: What is the use case where you are using `broken_bar_h`?  (un-related to the question at hand, doing user research for mpl ;) )

Comment: I found it as a perfect tool for tv guide visualisation ([example](http://cl.ly/image/0T3g2A301b3r)). Some time ago I did similar thing in ggplot and there I relied on `aes(xmin=,xmax=,ymin=,ymax=)`

Comment: Interesting.  That is a pretty cool figure!

Comment: Would be willing to submit a version of the code that generated that figure to the example gallery for mpl?

Comment: Of course! https://gist.github.com/trnl/3611b2947d02d90452b0

Comment: Can you open a PR with that code?  That is the easiest way get it reviewed.

Comment: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/3964

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, good question! You're diving into the gritty details, so there are a fair number of semi-undocumented details that you need to know.

Your current method would work except for two things:

1. The `clip_box` is expected to be in display coordinates, so you'll need to transform it.
2. It's not enough to use a "plain" `Bbox` for this. For the transform to data coordinates to be re-done every time the display changes, you'll need to use a `TransformedBbox`.

To demonstrate a bit more of what's going on, let's fix the first problem, but not the second:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
vals = [
        (10,20,"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"),
        (30,20, "Pellentesque scelerisque congue fermentum."),
        (50,10, "Aliquam erat volutpat")
]
ax.set_ylim(0,1)
ax.broken_barh(map(lambda v: v[:2],vals), (0, 1), 
              facecolors=('yellow','red','green'))
for v in vals:
    box = Bbox([[v[0],0],[v[0]+v[1],1]]).transformed(ax.transData)
    anno = ax.annotate(v[2], xy=(v[0],0.4), clip_box=box)

plt.show()
```

[image]

It looks good at first, but there's an additional problem: Because the `clip_box` is static and in display coordinates, it will be in the incorrect position as soon as you change the plot in any way (e.g. zoom, pan, autoscale, change the figure window size, change the figure DPI).

For example, if I hit the "save" button (or call `savefig`), the clip box will be incorrect because the DPI of the figure will be changed (from 80 to 100) before saving!

[image]

For that reason, you need to use a `TransformedBbox` for this.  It's just a version of `Bbox` that saves a reference to a transformation and re-transforms the underlying `Bbox` if the transformation changes.  There are a handful of `Transformed*` classes along these lines in matplotlib: e.g. `TransformedPath`, etc. They're not a level of detail you always need to know about, but they can be very useful.

As a final example, that will work correctly no matter how the plot is zoomed/panned/changed:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import TransformedBbox, Bbox

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
vals = [
        (10,20,"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"),
        (30,20, "Pellentesque scelerisque congue fermentum."),
        (50,10, "Aliquam erat volutpat")
]
ax.set_ylim(0,1)
ax.broken_barh(map(lambda v: v[:2],vals), (0, 1),
              facecolors=('yellow','red','green'))
for v in vals:
    box = TransformedBbox(Bbox([[v[0],0],[v[0]+v[1],1]]), ax.transData)
    anno = ax.annotate(v[2], xy=(v[0],0.4), clip_box=box)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you, that's very comprehensive answer!
One addition that I found - if you setting the clip_box to the bounds of the particular broken_barh, then the value of `clip_on=True` are discarded, so to fix this you need to pay attention to `ax.get_xlim()` while creating `TransformedBbox`.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html is helpful addition to this answer.